# How to get dashed line (with down arrow icon) SVG animation on accordingly scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation, svg

How can I add a down icon (Small) in the dotted line? Can you help me, please? Like this line:- [How to get dashed line svg animation on accordingly scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567563/how-to-get-dashed-line-svg-animation-on-accordingly-scroll)
Just have to add some down arrow in the dotted line.

Comment: It’s not very clear what is required. Could you put in your code so far and show what you have tried to add an arrow and describe where the arrow is to be in relation to the animated line.

Answer (score 1):

You can position an arrowhead shape at the head of the animated line by use the `path.getPointAtLength()` method.

Below is a cleaned-up version of the code you link to, with a bit of additional code to add the arrowhead and position it correctly as the scroll animation happens.

```js
var path = document.getElementById("thePath");
var mask = document.getElementById("maskPath");
var arrow = document.getElementById("arrowhead");

var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

// Initialise the mask dash pattern to patch the actual path length
mask.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength;

window.addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);


function myFunction() {
  var scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                      / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  var len = pathLength * scrollpercent;
  drawPathLength( len );
  drawArrowAtLength( len );
}


function drawPathLength(len) {
  mask.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength - len;
}


function drawArrowAtLength(len) {
  // Get the x,y coordinates of the path at length "len"
  var pos = path.getPointAtLength(len);
  // Reposition the arrowhead at that position
  arrow.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + pos.x + "," + pos.y + ")");
}


// Initialise the amount of drawn path to 0
drawPathLength(0);
// Initialise the arrowhead position to the start of the path
drawArrowAtLength(0);
```

```html
<h1>Scroll down</h1>
<svg width="198px" height="1483px" viewBox="0 0 198 1483">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="linearGradient-1">
      <stop stop-color="#DE1652" offset="0%"></stop>
      <stop stop-color="#F37121" offset="50.2239948%"></stop>
      <stop stop-color="#FBAB26" offset="100%"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    
    <!-- Note: the 'transform="translate(-646, -266)"' attributes present in this code is to compensate
     for the fact that the path has a large offset from the top left of the SVG. All it does is just move
     the path (and also the arrowhead) to a position where it is visible -->
     
    <path id="thePath"
      d="M702,266 C682,424 795.064639,474.307498 716,600 C599,786 769,821 688,988 C548.560405,1275.48657 822.815807,1223 840.843207,1373 C858.870608,1523 605.485477,1528 687.610302,1728"
      transform="translate(-646, -266)"
      fill="none" />

   <mask id="theMask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <use id="maskPath" xlink:href="#thePath"
           stroke="#fff" stroke-width="8" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <use id="visiblePath" xlink:href="#thePath"
       stroke-width="4"
       stroke-dasharray="12 16"
       stroke="url(#linearGradient-1)"
       mask="url(#theMask)" />
       
  <g transform="translate(-646, -266)">
    <polygon id="arrowhead"
             points="-10,0, 0,20, 10,0"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```